# How to read child nodes from each parent node using vba and write them to excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root Signature="{5DCBAC3B-D39C-497C-9BE8-744CBADD37AA}" NameVersion="4" Cookie="3447">
    <LogicalNodes Name="Aliases" Owner="{BE401E45-B2D6-4FBA-931A-C2117D5C51AD}">
            <Child0 Name="wndProgman" Owner="{AE704EB6-AD19-45EA-B496-41A5981E8412}">
                <Child0 Name="SHELLDLL_DefView" Owner="{610947DD-D55F-4A13-9CA5-E9088894FD86}">
                    <Child0 Name="FolderView" Owner="{15A15A12-D939-4C0A-8977-BAFAB4D04F43}" />
                </Child0>
            </Child0>
            <Child1 Name="wndShell_TrayWnd" Owner="{DAE8A331-ACA7-4945-8331-7A11E81306D0}">
                <Child0 Name="ReBarWindow32" Owner="{8DD1A6A4-CE21-47EB-B42E-30D5CF347E59}">
                    <Child0 Name="MSTaskSwWClass" Owner="{94EDC32F-6134-4847-870A-844B98B33ACC}">
                        <Child0 Name="MSTaskListWClass" Owner="{8816439D-7900-4047-B0C4-22DD7E60729C}" />
                    </Child0>
                </Child0>
            </Child1>
        </Child0>
        <Child1 Name="notepad" Owner="{449D4FD4-389C-4BEE-BCC2-8A6EC8BC73AB}">
            <Child0 Name="wndNotepad" Owner="{40D93496-0E10-4091-AC8E-9E6E476333FC}">
                <Child0 Name="Edit" Owner="{E0844148-8BB1-43B9-914E-4237ABEE2EC4}" />
            </Child0>
        </Child1>
        <Child2 Name="PorticoVT" Owner="{3EFC33EE-8634-4970-875C-F3BDEA8FA0EB}">
            <Child0 Name="wnd_HeartLandPortico" Owner="{62D04395-D5E2-42A4-8B36-5619A5B4AB6F}">
                <Child0 Name="browser_HeartLandPortico" Owner="{F5CB4FF9-DC18-4D49-B2CB-A31D82F60AEA}">
                    <Child0 Name="page_PorticoLogin" Owner="{AB2707EF-D4C1-43A7-B0F1-198CE11141D5}">
                        <Child0 Name="txt_LoginUserName" Owner="{EB0E205E-1832-4208-9957-D847514AFA9F}" />
                    </Child0>
                    <Child1 Name="page_PorticoHome" Owner="{AB2707EF-D4C1-43A7-B0F1-198CE11141D5}">
                        <Child0 Name="cmb_Sites" Owner="{4354AEA8-183E-47EA-95D8-D37C04E571EB}" />
                        <Child1 Name="cmb_Devices" Owner="{A5BFE04E-C3AB-4D76-ACCE-E0183FE6CB6C}" />
                        <Child2 Name="menu_Popup" Owner="{51670171-A8EA-4213-BEE3-135B00FF846B}">
                            <Child0 Name="Return" Owner="{71D611E7-1C99-4A81-A196-DBB2A84E4D2C}" />
                            <Child1 Name="Sale" Owner="{A2F629A5-2880-4B9F-B2DD-EB8208BED5F1}" />
                        </Child2>
                        <Child3 Name="btn_Logout" Owner="{9C3F168B-C4E8-4258-9BB9-87CC9E039FBD}" />
                        <Child4 Name="btn_Process" Owner="{07DFBDF4-6C09-4139-B6AD-2C50B0923BC2}" />
                        <Child5 Name="menu_SubFunctionalities" Owner="{6CCA1F99-BA33-44F7-9862-40DDE3BA9754}">
                            <Child0 Name="Authorization" Owner="{FD0D731E-F3C7-449A-8ECE-708D04E678AA}" />
                            <Child1 Name="Credit_Return" Owner="{1602182C-8EE3-4850-9EE9-B85169EEB8C7}" />
                            <Child2 Name="Offline_Sale" Owner="{200BC451-D439-4917-8074-AE199A7F9E1F}" />
                            <Child3 Name="Offline_Authorization" Owner="{CD66638D-2DA2-475F-A7E8-A08F7AE699EB}" />
                            <Child4 Name="Tip_Adjustment" Owner="{75DEE507-E479-466F-8C1B-DEE53DBF9086}" />
                            <Child5 Name="MOTO_E_Commerce" Owner="{38EFF717-EFFD-42A9-97BE-08CC1DCB1241}" />
                            <Child6 Name="Check_Verify_Only" Owner="{CF9E9E51-7F60-4685-B261-4C6B952E92C6}" />
                            <Child7 Name="Check_One_Time_ACH" Owner="{19A30406-3B70-4439-8137-65ED56DA015B}" />
                            <Child8 Name="HMS_Redeem" Owner="{DDF674EB-4C86-4132-AA64-E207C8790585}" />
                            <Child9 Name="HMS_Load" Owner="{68C7E4CC-9401-4081-943A-CFBE832589BE}" />
                            <Child10 Name="HMS_Activate" Owner="{D5457A26-C6BD-4FFE-AA11-320AD8380790}" />
                            <Child11 Name="HMS_Reward" Owner="{363CB1F2-CEE8-4FD1-909D-AE38709817D9}" />
                            <Child12 Name="HMS_Transfer" Owner="{C38D7143-5B7F-410C-82C3-D5D5CAC96B8C}" />
                            <Child13 Name="HMS_Add_Alias" Owner="{B3FBD0B4-C998-432D-81BF-F351CCDBC72C}" />
                            <Child14 Name="HMS_Remove_Alias" Owner="{E8EA3B6E-FFBD-4924-A60F-DE6610A34581}" />
                            <Child15 Name="Prepaid_Add_Value" Owner="{4A880530-E28D-45A0-8326-21AD4DD12205}" />
                            <Child16 Name="Check_Sale" Owner="{8123F966-8AA1-478B-99FC-0D3C22128D90}" />
                            <Child17 Name="HMS_Balance_Inquiry" Owner="{9DEB16E5-44E7-4A5B-8F7F-23A4EBA60861}" />
                            <Child18 Name="EBT_Food_Stamp_Sale" Owner="{FE300955-B674-4331-B3DA-56087599AE27}" />
                            <Child19 Name="EBT_Food_Stamp_Voucher" Owner="{C292106D-CDD0-4363-AD1F-16F4EE7AD560}" />
                            <Child20 Name="EBT_Cash_Benefit_Sale" Owner="{EE4383E5-4D81-4524-92E2-A74AA7970A87}" />
                            <Child21 Name="EBT_Food_Stamp_Return" Owner="{AF37C57C-1B7A-4F6B-BF6E-2F9AF31C5FD3}" />
                            <Child22 Name="EBT_Food_Stamp_Balance_Inquiry" Owner="{BD25AA42-3944-4554-964F-CA551B85A365}" />
                            <Child23 Name="Account_Verify" Owner="{DEC3565E-B6F8-4E37-86CE-90C0FF3AC1A8}" />
                            <Child24 Name="dlg_Error" Owner="{69463272-1A26-46DC-B675-FA7550CBFBA9}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{29B84C6F-A0D5-49B6-B2EF-CA67C68517DB}" />
                                <Child1 Name="FR_Possible_fraud_detected_" Owner="{86C16C91-9689-46A9-A342-A0C08BB310AC}" />
                                <Child2 Name="NoButton" Owner="{9E406710-E2A0-4A79-A9D6-C14712B13E34}" />
                                <Child3 Name="Error" Owner="{15542A5E-D066-4D11-8108-AEE670D346DA}" />
                            </Child24>
                            <Child25 Name="Commercial_Card_Prompt" Owner="{19F433EF-8931-4EC7-8987-0E1FB0775257}">
                                <Child0 Name="Commercial_Card_Prompt" Owner="{B9262AB2-DA37-4288-B87D-F6DB03827573}" />
                                <Child1 Name="PO_Number" Owner="{CE44A904-8A3B-4F5D-A43D-BB01D37170C5}" />
                            </Child25>
                            <Child26 Name="ChildWindow" Owner="{7416B297-CEC8-42F2-8123-A2A1C2EE77FE}">
                                <Child0 Name="ResultsGrid" Owner="{26A9D1C1-8905-43D1-BC74-1F817E53A520}" />
                                <Child1 Name="OkButton" Owner="{CD3722E5-7B56-450B-A5DD-69C6B6682E85}" />
                                <Child2 Name="AddDocumentControl" Owner="{86D0C2C9-C7A9-440B-A8ED-F4AE9CBE2DA6}" />
                                <Child3 Name="txt_recipient" Owner="{DEBB303D-EB6F-4037-BC31-CDF5D7C4EA08}" />
                                <Child4 Name="RepeatSaleControl" Owner="{F371CC4B-8612-4224-A9BC-A4C97F5A5668}" />
                                <Child5 Name="TipAdjustmentControl" Owner="{F2762A53-5750-47DC-8E4C-91F2872EE840}" />
                                <Child6 Name="ReturnControl" Owner="{1B357D4D-065E-4F9F-B252-F2133D0B11A1}" />
                                <Child7 Name="AddToBatchControl" Owner="{F5B213B3-2FFB-4289-9A7A-FEF403A49980}" />
                                <Child8 Name="VoidControl" Owner="{BA064BC9-16D1-4D2F-849A-645E58CDDB21}" />
                                <Child9 Name="txt_Recipients" Owner="{EAD01CA6-B449-4F9F-ADE7-8A190E9C344C}" />
                            </Child26>
                            <Child27 Name="Declined" Owner="{B2FD13E5-4CBB-4FCF-8931-941A262B4345}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{29270C7D-5995-4F9A-81B3-253DBD6EDF60}" />
                            </Child27>
                            <Child28 Name="Void_Confirmation" Owner="{B3A26216-078B-4793-8DCE-38350466D986}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{040E96A0-2C8A-42BA-8BFA-ECDCD7506C35}" />
                            </Child28>
                            <Child29 Name="Batch_Close_Confirmation" Owner="{D82695FB-05BB-42A3-B7B6-81E1BC0A0EF6}" />
                            <Child30 Name="Notification" Owner="{4C650AD1-EEF8-463D-A26A-7B1FA13277B3}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{F2A1082A-DF29-403F-A6DD-09277D3C5534}" />
                                <Child1 Name="Notification" Owner="{DBABEF5C-81F6-40A9-9F68-E681B94D0BFB}" />
                            </Child30>
                            <Child31 Name="About" Owner="{100ECAE5-9B02-442B-AF77-B89A3A0AD4D4}">
                                <Child0 Name="RichTextBox" Owner="{E37236C8-741C-41B7-AAA7-27D48946D099}" />
                            </Child31>
                            <Child32 Name="Success" Owner="{CDEE64E2-DFA9-4E2D-AE40-3F3083B2CF56}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{E50525B2-F6AF-45B5-8CB5-53E84D964962}" />
                            </Child32>
                            <Child33 Name="Delete_Confirmation" Owner="{334139E2-5E2F-4C23-AA2F-C6AFD66E41FF}" />
                            <Child34 Name="Next_Bill_Date" Owner="{E5010D0F-895A-4168-A241-2B3FC0B73827}">
                                <Child0 Name="Change_due_date_for_all_future_transactions" Owner="{C2D3AC47-C113-4B2F-BEE5-CA66E8C67C0C}" />
                                <Child1 Name="One_time_change" Owner="{12A0C6B0-F53F-4139-A921-F155FD5DF334}" />
                                <Child2 Name="Continue" Owner="{60BF6041-D119-4FC7-915B-2912F5AA9DE7}" />
                            </Child34>
                            <Child35 Name="Sale_By_Tran_ID" Owner="{E014A1C1-A498-48CE-9E61-8B46DCEBFFE9}" />
                            <Child36 Name="Tip_Adjustment2" Owner="{29030CC3-A5BD-4669-8ACB-4C8A68EA0118}" />
                            <Child37 Name="Tip_Adjustment_Confirmation" Owner="{73F81679-4FCB-45DB-9959-68210A708B83}" />
                            <Child38 Name="Return_Prompt" Owner="{14F1D112-5B3F-4EA1-9726-5FFBDC5EB4AA}" />
                            <Child39 Name="Return_Confirmation" Owner="{00003714-4A58-4014-ADD4-4599D0C04ADB}" />
                            <Child40 Name="Impersonate" Owner="{C47364F8-76CD-4E14-ABAA-C8861ABDE868}">
                                <Child0 Name="Search" Owner="{6CA2360A-DDD5-4D96-9A14-3ED62D952E26}" />
                                <Child1 Name="Merchant_ID_" Owner="{26095961-AC3B-4524-9EAE-D5F1A543E2A3}" />
                                <Child2 Name="resultsDataGrid" Owner="{C5AFB58D-4C7C-4F61-8CE8-48DE094C15BD}" />
                                <Child3 Name="Devices_" Owner="{8E6995B4-F5E5-4ECC-B61C-3201DFD9AFB3}" />
                                <Child4 Name="ComboBox" Owner="{BD6F89FE-A5E6-44E5-B6BF-C4D8278E87B7}" />
                                <Child5 Name="searchParameterTextBox" Owner="{4A87BC39-741A-44FB-A776-2D14687F6EF1}" />
                                <Child6 Name="Impersonate_2" Owner="{72A37B7F-EA72-4B90-8B82-BA4DBB9CA06B}" />
                                <Child7 Name="Cancel" Owner="{61EA2455-9D5D-4DED-A077-1629A0B5AEC9}" />
                            </Child40>
                            <Child41 Name="BatchCloseConfirmation" Owner="{6FCA1EAD-EA31-47BA-A77B-0CCB7A2787E7}">
                                <Child0 Name="Yes" Owner="{84FC2583-0336-40F5-946C-3E3AED2C5B52}" />
                                <Child1 Name="No" Owner="{C9032129-E791-47AB-8AF9-EC12F3CF65DD}" />
                            </Child41>
                            <Child42 Name="Add_To_Batch" Owner="{B7D893B3-3747-41BC-AA54-47DC865711B6}">
                                <Child0 Name="OkButton" Owner="{9C9CD291-F232-4C62-B1A7-23339F341F52}" />
                                <Child1 Name="CancelButton" Owner="{A083769F-E3C4-43BD-914A-FAB642B9200C}" />
                            </Child42>
                            <Child43 Name="Tip_Adjustment_Transaction_not_in_Batch" Owner="{7BC2D6C7-487E-4092-A999-7F085357C08F}" />
                            <Child44 Name="Override_Confirmation" Owner="{FC7D7FD6-BD76-4CC0-858D-5EE34D80F77E}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{389E1CD1-80FD-408B-9ABB-9E6BA7D0245E}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Override" Owner="{43A4A7D8-11F8-4831-BCC7-DECFFCDAC21E}" />
                                </Child0>
                            </Child44>
                            <Child45 Name="Print_Preview_Historical_Batch" Owner="{8A2BE18A-60B1-4EBC-B06F-AAFE9ED274A5}">
                                <Child0 Name="CloseButton" Owner="{9B31A1EB-008D-46EC-915E-4D0E42F7C068}" />
                            </Child45>
                            <Child46 Name="Result" Owner="{98F69015-12BF-4858-912B-2A5E34D7087F}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{EED6049E-D167-41E1-BE25-D327627679C9}" />
                                <Child1 Name="Result" Owner="{3C74576E-5AA0-486B-9A6E-ED85D6212C3B}" />
                            </Child46>
                            <Child47 Name="Prompt" Owner="{A195F989-7F1D-49A6-B2E8-76FEB2B59A96}">
                                <Child0 Name="Prompt" Owner="{8B969EFF-51D3-474A-9372-ABBD02F15A1F}" />
                            </Child47>
                        </Child5>
                        <Child6 Name="txt_recipient" Owner="{AE6661B6-E810-4A84-803C-016C326465C7}" />
                        <Child7 Name="lbl_EmailProcessed" Owner="{9F0212F6-F729-4A1F-8EFC-B714E95A537F}" />
                        <Child8 Name="btn_EmailSent_OK" Owner="{FDE9A59F-F6C7-4887-B1F8-C45C4476531C}" />
                        <Child9 Name="FooterFrame" Owner="{580E3699-D7AD-4FA0-9AC6-6FFB4917367C}">
                            <Child0 Name="lbl_ApplicationVersion" Owner="{413156BD-8222-42E4-A444-692BD0576D57}" />
                        </Child9>
                        <Child10 Name="menu_MainFunctionalities" Owner="{C4098CD6-F0BB-44ED-AACD-20E1125AB2D1}">
                            <Child0 Name="Debit" Owner="{49553D88-5B4C-47F1-9B0E-CD312E16B29B}" />
                            <Child1 Name="HMS" Owner="{8B485103-E06C-4224-8A9B-03DB93A20C6E}" />
                            <Child2 Name="PrePaid" Owner="{2008F221-26A1-44D5-A64D-091C14823454}" />
                            <Child3 Name="EBT" Owner="{CDED5FF8-1F80-4AFE-94B3-C7E416A101C6}" />
                            <Child4 Name="Reporting" Owner="{5DF2D460-6A03-4D38-A73C-D6BA5CFABFF8}" />
                            <Child5 Name="Admin" Owner="{66080613-20FF-4B28-BDB9-058FCEF6D360}" />
                            <Child6 Name="Support" Owner="{3A858F34-FF5A-434A-847D-5FA448D30B7A}" />
                            <Child7 Name="lbl_Errors" Owner="{04353457-8412-497B-B084-623B0AD2E3A1}" />
                            <Child8 Name="ResultsDataGrid" Owner="{195F7694-204B-4F0E-AA2D-D2E98A2A21C6}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{5CE39D67-776E-4225-B9B6-839B20DFE4BD}" />
                            </Child8>
                            <Child9 Name="PayPlan" Owner="{E0531421-0946-4F47-BB72-64667A56EF86}" />
                            <Child10 Name="Cancel_Impersonation" Owner="{02B95C87-7C92-4219-BF38-6FD5DA413445}" />
                            <Child11 Name="BreadcrumbFrame" Owner="{2CAFCECA-3C35-4C47-831A-2EF4E870096F}">
                                <Child0 Name="Failed_Schedules_Detail" Owner="{FC45C190-4EC9-4818-AABA-5656709CBD07}" />
                            </Child11>
                        </Child10>
                        <Child11 Name="lbl_Header" Owner="{26E6DD3F-D5E5-42CE-BAD2-139BCB024CE5}" />
                        <Child12 Name="GridContainer" Owner="{86E0BB19-3E03-4296-9B63-072F56ACCFAB}">
                            <Child0 Name="TipAmountTextBox" Owner="{10B394EA-9E71-4564-BAB5-801231FCB977}" />
                        </Child12>
                        <Child13 Name="dlg_Success" Owner="{7AB3A048-A37A-45DE-8375-FD37CAD432C5}" />
                        <Child14 Name="lbl_Errors" Owner="{6D47D531-C537-4D2B-98C7-FF9F2A0B78E4}" />
                        <Child15 Name="Close_Batch" Owner="{C138C485-42D5-4AEC-9FB5-25D03D9C6E61}" />
                        <Child16 Name="btn_Export" Owner="{8991805F-EC88-4F23-9027-28D7E7C89444}" />
                        <Child17 Name="popup_Export" Owner="{5DD87E3F-C854-4F2E-BE1B-20CE50D85467}">
                            <Child0 Name="XML" Owner="{501EB044-8779-4246-A94C-58DA989A3EC5}" />
                            <Child1 Name="PDF" Owner="{1612790B-F3AB-4510-9F38-5CDC10A29782}" />
                            <Child2 Name="CSV" Owner="{471B8428-5826-4BF0-BB74-2EE5FBCA4607}" />
                            <Child3 Name="Tab_Delimited" Owner="{E9EC5CBE-0AB0-44DD-9A0A-9B682CBAE2A3}" />
                            <Child4 Name="Excel" Owner="{0DA3F679-87E9-4565-89F5-8FA21E026F82}" />
                        </Child17>
                        <Child18 Name="InputScrollViewer" Owner="{A9D51C9E-E473-409F-BD1B-700A89C47C79}">
                            <Child0 Name="Grid1" Owner="{7D49E839-B8F4-478E-9C1A-615E59B53E8B}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{27F356B6-37BA-4B6B-8313-9B1FCA30D299}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Payment_" Owner="{5887EEF4-E1E0-4182-927B-03DB1430F3B8}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{34DFAFF3-7A1B-4655-8B98-FCC2D12080EB}">
                                            <Child0 Name="TextBox" Owner="{1A30F689-71FE-4670-83F5-6D9BD5A6C157}" />
                                            <Child1 Name="Charge" Owner="{7D9B2BE5-5B68-4BF2-87EC-1820B7530B76}" />
                                        </Child0>
                                        <Child1 Name="DataGridCell2" Owner="{4D6D5BD8-D857-4C88-B053-462C85711289}">
                                            <Child0 Name="Button" Owner="{BF7A1BFE-AB51-41A1-A633-47952269DF54}">
                                                <Child0 Name="EditImage" Owner="{CA4A6F58-61E3-407A-B4E0-40AB444AE279}" />
                                            </Child0>
                                            <Child1 Name="Button2" Owner="{7D493838-CDF6-4AD3-AC3D-6AEE07FBF9CB}" />
                                        </Child1>
                                        <Child2 Name="DataGridCell3" Owner="{7826B845-040D-4EC8-9B22-722F9D19DBFB}">
                                            <Child0 Name="Charge_Now" Owner="{A1330906-6F2C-4D0C-9EBB-BFE937740312}" />
                                        </Child2>
                                    </Child0>
                                </Child0>
                            </Child0>
                            <Child1 Name="Grid2" Owner="{0391870C-1EC1-4A15-9DD5-F597164D6849}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{6CF7191D-AEF3-45D8-A7B2-9CC2917307C6}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Schedule_" Owner="{CF01792B-0EEA-4D6D-ADDF-E05B6A1DA99C}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{699998EB-EAD8-4FEF-9FCC-01D68D9FFF4B}">
                                            <Child0 Name="Button" Owner="{99CFBA63-858B-4BDA-BDD9-187CFDC2B00E}" />
                                            <Child1 Name="Button2" Owner="{2DA4596E-18CA-45E5-B1F4-287E13523B68}" />
                                        </Child0>
                                    </Child0>
                                </Child0>
                            </Child1>
                            <Child2 Name="st_and_15th_day_of_each_month" Owner="{E3DE947C-D452-4A13-B15C-587C34599105}">
                                <Child0 Name="st_and_15th_day_of_each_month" Owner="{2FDC93B2-302E-49C1-BD6F-E81944138BD2}" />
                            </Child2>
                            <Child3 Name="th_and_last_day_of_each_month" Owner="{70594E6C-70B4-4F03-815E-FB56C5946549}">
                                <Child0 Name="th_and_last_day_of_each_month" Owner="{B6ECEF22-3275-427B-BE02-8F04E7FA0075}" />
                            </Child3>
                            <Child4 Name="Search" Owner="{B7E6B80E-098F-40AE-B578-807C355D4DD2}" />
                            <Child5 Name="Close_Batch" Owner="{9C232C49-5779-4316-A401-AD16202F9E3D}" />
                            <Child6 Name="ResultsDataGrid" Owner="{9D1A681F-734D-4288-A4BA-B2910195568D}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{9844CD57-8701-466C-A36A-506B22C91021}" />
                                <Child1 Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Owner="{6482B3A6-5F72-40EC-9690-336BA8FDADE3}" />
                            </Child6>
                            <Child7 Name="VerticalScrollBar" Owner="{0C9FF91F-6C7E-41D6-8D62-B8EB34D5152D}" />
                            <Child8 Name="ResultsDataGrid2" Owner="{87BB63BA-84A5-4EAB-9C33-D8118D285006}" />
                            <Child9 Name="Edit_Customer" Owner="{6F4F6960-2A37-4C6A-B101-7D0DA12CA08B}" />
                            <Child10 Name="Charge_Now" Owner="{62863E18-E0CA-4B78-BD36-518F68FDF280}" />
                            <Child11 Name="Add_New_Payment_Method" Owner="{76D8B76A-286D-4BF1-8C7C-5071CF7131F3}" />
                            <Child12 Name="Add_Payment_Method" Owner="{7CBFE201-0B17-485E-874E-66557D161F6F}" />
                            <Child13 Name="Add_Schedule" Owner="{AD5A8F31-0BB4-45DB-9AF5-DB2A9E9EE856}" />
                            <Child14 Name="Update" Owner="{934FF193-8D0D-4ED2-A19A-5EFC75E77594}" />
                            <Child15 Name="No_Records" Owner="{9B5F9762-6565-4501-93B4-E604852B9C14}" />
                            <Child16 Name="SummaryListBox" Owner="{EE9937D1-19CD-4368-A3F1-D5F584C48443}" />
                            <Child17 Name="errorsMessage" Owner="{CFDFAE1C-9D0B-43EB-A476-678ACF5C2BB7}" />
                        </Child18>
                    </Child1>
                    <Child2 Name="page_PorticoFunctionalilties" Owner="{001B2F54-E626-409C-8A8F-A54F57C49883}">
                        <Child0 Name="menu_MainFunctionalities" Owner="{E5E32C4B-D1D1-4271-970E-D421A3A4435C}">
                            <Child0 Name="ContentFrame" Owner="{78341657-9CBF-482F-A26A-5EA62C21270A}">
                                <Child0 Name="GridContainer" Owner="{59593BE3-08CD-42C3-9551-7CCB8E75A4EA}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Credit_Card_Details" Owner="{661DFF05-EC2F-4ACD-9660-747A00A91A1A}" />
                                </Child0>
                                <Child1 Name="AM" Owner="{EF88623A-CC5A-4292-BA24-9D793A31380A}">
                                    <Child0 Name="StartDateDatePicker" Owner="{354E5284-EDAE-4D7C-9029-18EA8C70B521}" />
                                </Child1>
                                <Child2 Name="Search" Owner="{A8B3BD0B-D501-4B8F-A999-052372591003}" />
                            </Child0>
                            <Child1 Name="Credit" Owner="{4DEACF7C-B8BE-45D5-AC58-1277A8046FAC}" />
                            <Child2 Name="Debit" Owner="{4AC66505-123D-468E-BB26-A49490FABFD7}" />
                            <Child3 Name="Check" Owner="{B3E19A37-7E51-4379-998F-77D5ACF15624}" />
                            <Child4 Name="HMS" Owner="{412CC1DE-3AEF-4111-A8B6-D2CC1CFB1181}" />
                            <Child5 Name="PrePaid" Owner="{AF690C58-B55D-4E3C-8DF5-33E2C446C4BA}" />
                            <Child6 Name="EBT" Owner="{6049FE2E-0F45-4E1A-B6EB-EC97E90CB88A}" />
                            <Child7 Name="Reporting" Owner="{E4A26052-EC04-42B2-A1F7-664EF4A7645D}" />
                            <Child8 Name="Admin" Owner="{0B804D68-BAC8-426A-BCA9-E7786CDEB031}" />
                            <Child9 Name="Support" Owner="{52F2F374-1684-4290-B3D9-691EBDCD0D37}" />
                            <Child10 Name="HeaderFrame" Owner="{AD49DD7F-7138-484B-A85E-61B19A0BAF1C}">
                                <Child0 Name="btn_Apply" Owner="{DD997C8E-5D89-4683-A125-E9A3B54CFF94}" />
                            </Child10>
                            <Child11 Name="txt_LoginUserName" Owner="{899FA620-64EF-4849-A388-A7C4DF61CB38}" />
                            <Child12 Name="txt_LoginPassword" Owner="{26D78B49-71E2-4F2A-8453-1769B67DB64B}" />
                            <Child13 Name="btn_Login" Owner="{4F9B29B7-0ACA-466A-89FF-6C8A0AC57724}" />
                        </Child0>
                        <Child1 Name="menu_Credit" Owner="{EF9A7C69-43E6-47DF-88E8-67A6849D928D}" />
                        <Child2 Name="page_Results" Owner="{AFDEAE52-E9D4-441B-A04F-FE15C6815BBF}">
                            <Child0 Name="btn_EmailControl" Owner="{6BAC9947-FDF2-4F04-8A32-D89B02FBB46F}" />
                            <Child1 Name="btn_PrintControl" Owner="{293B9ECA-00E5-49E2-9387-79F6F23918F2}" />
                            <Child2 Name="grd_Results" Owner="{1B08B2BA-9A20-421F-9A1B-D16C57679857}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{EE6BAE45-E4FA-4BFB-9069-6BCD2EFCAFAE}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Hps_VT_UI_Presentation_Controls_TransactionResultItem" Owner="{9DCB2E6B-BC9E-4985-A439-924C02B85062}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{9E1FC0FF-5B75-4CE3-8DC3-FF148F05DD0B}">
                                            <Child0 Name="TextBlock" Owner="{CC1F8906-FC56-409D-B9A0-A922A8E111F6}" />
                                        </Child0>
                                        <Child1 Name="DataGridCell2" Owner="{F088DF96-3E71-450C-95AF-7FD1F4EFB638}">
                                            <Child0 Name="TextBlock" Owner="{5BE59093-814B-4AB1-929F-2287F8A7B0B8}" />
                                        </Child1>
                                    </Child0>
                                    <Child1 Name="Hps_VT_UI_Presentation_Controls_TransactionResultItem_2" Owner="{FD344257-DA1B-46C3-9229-3B0516C2FB4B}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{DEF9EA62-3D10-4B12-8E7C-517D6E0409F3}" />
                                        <Child1 Name="DataGridCell2" Owner="{7CBBBB7B-FA3B-4E43-A655-BC4BF3DBF99D}" />
                                    </Child1>
                                    <Child2 Name="Hps_VT_UI_Presentation_Controls_TransactionResultItem_16" Owner="{615169A2-09BE-477D-A275-8D95921A09DD}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{EFBF5725-72B0-4115-AFCC-75A939BEFCD4}" />
                                    </Child2>
                                </Child0>
                            </Child2>
                            <Child3 Name="txt_Recipient" Owner="{68C2111F-3F5E-4FA5-B658-B1504C9C73CA}" />
                            <Child4 Name="btn_SendEmail" Owner="{81F48E23-BC0A-4D4D-A781-D94148E6FDD4}" />
                            <Child5 Name="btn_OK" Owner="{21E755EA-8C6C-4449-A4C7-4A16C525E64A}" />
                            <Child6 Name="btn_AddAttachment" Owner="{01E97D5D-BF33-42B6-8CB6-22881DA1585B}" />
                            <Child7 Name="VoidControl" Owner="{031BB042-1089-4587-94C7-9451FA22F95C}" />
                            <Child8 Name="OK" Owner="{AD2449ED-5640-4AF9-8C4E-E6B22BE34E06}" />
                            <Child9 Name="TipAdjustmentControl" Owner="{1AF35C78-CA99-43F6-A8A0-8AB04E1C1B85}" />
                        </Child2>
                        <Child3 Name="Debit_Return" Owner="{13F9ECA1-3C4E-4BEF-997C-FA6021245CD9}" />
                        <Child4 Name="Error" Owner="{53183FBF-7020-4B86-BD34-3C0C8FE85B5A}">
                            <Child0 Name="Error" Owner="{6B5971B5-EA9B-48ED-8B3D-25F47C4D63FE}" />
                            <Child1 Name="YesButton" Owner="{576292E6-7D9A-4E69-8851-E62611D4F24E}" />
                        </Child4>
                        <Child5 Name="menu_SubFunctionalities" Owner="{161A0723-97E9-49B5-B2CD-47B01C543372}">
                            <Child0 Name="ChildWindow" Owner="{AFDEAE52-E9D4-441B-A04F-FE15C6815BBF}">
                                <Child0 Name="ResultsGrid" Owner="{1B08B2BA-9A20-421F-9A1B-D16C57679857}" />
                                <Child1 Name="Approved" Owner="{A29737C2-9683-4FCF-BEAB-76243EAD8293}" />
                                <Child2 Name="EmailControl" Owner="{6BAC9947-FDF2-4F04-8A32-D89B02FBB46F}" />
                                <Child3 Name="PrintControl" Owner="{293B9ECA-00E5-49E2-9387-79F6F23918F2}" />
                                <Child4 Name="Recipient" Owner="{68C2111F-3F5E-4FA5-B658-B1504C9C73CA}" />
                                <Child5 Name="SendEmail" Owner="{81F48E23-BC0A-4D4D-A781-D94148E6FDD4}" />
                                <Child6 Name="OkButton" Owner="{21E755EA-8C6C-4449-A4C7-4A16C525E64A}" />
                                <Child7 Name="ZIP_Code" Owner="{2C8BBAC6-BC3C-4E5B-B44E-7DB051DF5EAC}" />
                                <Child8 Name="Name" Owner="{8B93E482-2835-4CF1-AF0C-528502855F7C}" />
                                <Child9 Name="Transaction_Type" Owner="{D0CAB55E-9204-458E-8A5F-C791DD110FC8}" />
                                <Child10 Name="Customer_Copy" Owner="{B812140A-8FED-48B6-A596-B4CA9FAF5E63}" />
                                <Child11 Name="Date_" Owner="{C640653F-72FE-44F6-A20D-D01E5F45FC54}" />
                                <Child12 Name="ClosePreview" Owner="{6A3F8191-444B-4480-9FD0-C5579DA644A8}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Cancel" Owner="{A769E97B-E023-4664-A5AF-564FCD0DB225}" />
                                </Child12>
                                <Child13 Name="www_google_com" Owner="{9B08CD3B-3C86-4354-9B21-61E681A617D2}" />
                            </Child0>
                            <Child1 Name="MOTO_E_Commerce" Owner="{E9698F3C-FC8F-4094-B50E-77538B01CC67}" />
                            <Child2 Name="Balance_Inquiry" Owner="{6658094F-672E-4165-8162-5C41B76291EE}" />
                            <Child3 Name="Sale" Owner="{656D793F-4A90-450A-B4A0-879CB6D42058}" />
                            <Child4 Name="Error" Owner="{53183FBF-7020-4B86-BD34-3C0C8FE85B5A}" />
                            <Child5 Name="Commercial_Card_Prompt" Owner="{C7961684-E09F-40C2-B41F-C99EF35F65AC}">
                                <Child0 Name="CpcPoNumberTextBox" Owner="{47892ACC-8A71-4CEB-9A91-E29F6A97FBB0}">
                                    <Child0 Name="ContentElement" Owner="{F947DECF-DBA5-43AE-9471-80B62632998D}" />
                                </Child0>
                                <Child1 Name="CpcTaxAmountTextBox" Owner="{A0222A1B-5AE6-4EA5-BA29-20AF7C302F59}" />
                                <Child2 Name="CpcTaxExemptCheckBox" Owner="{B1B104E2-7710-4DE7-85E0-9FD0C671C1EA}" />
                                <Child3 Name="CpcProcessButton" Owner="{11FF064A-E1E8-498E-A924-8B0DA3FF10CF}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Process" Owner="{9A0A2394-E85B-4692-ABDC-27742A6F8B38}" />
                                </Child3>
                            </Child5>
                            <Child6 Name="Credit_Return" Owner="{CCCA5F97-A4BF-4F76-8F08-981701BABC90}" />
                            <Child7 Name="dlg_Declined" Owner="{C457D077-F6BB-4384-AF18-06B6B2006D21}" />
                            <Child8 Name="dlg_Success" Owner="{54229E09-FAB7-41F3-A42A-13BF26C017BA}" />
                            <Child9 Name="Tip_Adjustment" Owner="{885BD5B9-282C-4729-94C6-7DA001B83375}" />
                            <Child10 Name="About" Owner="{FA73E9CE-1215-42A9-9DCD-E1CCA5FE4AFD}" />
                            <Child11 Name="Notification" Owner="{90F5F1BE-1FA4-4BBC-862F-C5A2FC22CB5B}">
                                <Child0 Name="YesButton" Owner="{9BABE2F4-7F29-496D-BC5D-4C66EED5D607}">
                                    <Child0 Name="OK" Owner="{9B95054D-5C65-4991-BD7C-3EEB498E51FD}" />
                                </Child0>
                            </Child11>
                            <Child12 Name="AMEX_Advance_Notice" Owner="{2D22F6A1-8846-4850-89C4-2FCB2009D088}">
                                <Child0 Name="Continue" Owner="{83705DE4-B841-4B60-9C6B-56D1479C1970}" />
                            </Child12>
                            <Child13 Name="Email_not_on_File" Owner="{E2D4092C-5AB1-44EB-A8B9-3688423E4077}" />                             
                        </Child5>
                        <Child6 Name="InputScrollViewer" Owner="{681A6371-7BCE-417E-9E34-59949AB64F0B}">
                            <Child0 Name="Edit_Customer" Owner="{BC1F4586-0C1E-4FD3-A05D-B64A99EC1943}" />
                            <Child1 Name="Update" Owner="{25131BBC-93B8-4F6C-B098-CCADAF5BDC32}" />
                            <Child2 Name="Grid2" Owner="{52541876-6A87-41F3-B94C-19D25137421E}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{8F96569C-4DE4-46EE-95C6-66E93AD48288}">
                                    <Child0 Name="Schedule_" Owner="{AA5E2F62-73B2-433D-BB41-BC718C667476}">
                                        <Child0 Name="DataGridCell" Owner="{0FD2FE71-92A8-4DA4-8FED-9547EC35A95C}">
                                            <Child0 Name="Button" Owner="{8A00D074-8A02-4EFB-A14F-5489D016A1BD}">
                                                <Child0 Name="EditImage" Owner="{2251D415-40AD-4A93-96C7-113CBC71A500}" />
                                            </Child0>
                                        </Child0>
                                    </Child0>
                                </Child0>
                            </Child2>
                            <Child3 Name="ResultsDataGrid" Owner="{7EDA56F5-49CC-42C7-935E-F7EF7552DAE8}">
                                <Child0 Name="RowsPresenter" Owner="{BCD45A30-3F69-4BB8-9233-DFD5D241A747}" />
                            </Child3>
                            <Child4 Name="Add_Payment_Method" Owner="{B675B510-9A6B-4C41-9B53-408D45F1A9D1}" />
                            <Child5 Name="Add_Schedule" Owner="{95C57751-C5E0-4A59-981B-7043026BD617}" />
                            <Child6 Name="Add_New_Payment_Method" Owner="{45A056DF-99DF-40B6-8DBF-D6ECCBC4754F}" />
                            <Child7 Name="Delete" Owner="{B8D58D44-438F-4F48-A48B-E9BB1C795D20}" />
                            <Child8 Name="VerticalScrollBar" Owner="{5E299DD0-7057-4C2B-AA9D-61B803361F07}" />
                            <Child9 Name="Page_1_of_2" Owner="{E4C921A6-4D91-4F09-B85C-C7BB659CD183}" />
                            <Child10 Name="Cancel" Owner="{1BD6B4F6-228D-4620-A0A2-8606302A81C5}" />
                        </Child6>
                    </Child2>
                </Child0>
            </Child0>
            <Child1 Name="dlg_Open" Owner="{D2829184-6A42-48D4-ADF2-10A416C40146}">
                <Child0 Name="cmb_File" Owner="{2DCC40E5-86FB-46B3-B8A4-16E15ACD854E}">
                    <Child0 Name="cmb_FileName" Owner="{551C1C3E-81B1-4B51-B86E-9A82317CF4B1}">
                        <Child0 Name="txt_FileName" Owner="{ED3459CD-F98C-46E4-ABC3-C834E38522E7}" />
                    </Child0>
                </Child0>
                <Child1 Name="btn_Open" Owner="{05CC7DCA-80FB-40F4-A427-3FE0756F9E4D}" />
            </Child1>
        </Child2>
    </LogicalNodes>
</Root>
```

This xml should be parsed at child level and their values should be written to excel using vba.
(or)
How to read child nodes from each parent node using vba and write them to excel.
Can someone help with this

[image: Expected ouput]

Comment: This question lacks essential information. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: That is better, but as the XML has no actual tag contents, your question to have *their values written to excel* is not clear. Please provide an example list as it should appear in Excel. This could be attribute values (which?), nest level, tag names,... so be specific.

Comment: Why don't you put that in the question? This is unreadable in the comments section.

Comment: It has been updated as an Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is not valid because there is an opening *Child* tag missing right after the *LogicalNodes* tag opens.

In the code below I assumed the XML starts like this, with the *missing* node on the 4th line:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root Signature="{5DCBAC3B-D39C-497C-9BE8-744CBADD37AA}" NameVersion="4" Cookie="3447">
    <LogicalNodes Name="Aliases" Owner="{BE401E45-B2D6-4FBA-931A-C2117D5C51AD}">
        <Child0 Name="missing" Owner="{449D4FD4-389C-4BEE-BCC2-8A6EC8BC73AB}">
```

Once you've fixed that, here are some ways to load and display the nodes in Excel.

First include the reference to be able to parse XML:

- Open your VBA application editor
- From the menu choose **Tools > References**;
- Scroll through the list and tick *Microsoft XML, v6.0* from the list;
- OK to close.

### 1. Display name attribute values, children at the right of their parent

```vb
Function DisplayXmlTree(xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, attrName As String, _
                        target As Range, Optional depth As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    Dim xmlChildNode  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xmlAttr       As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim col           As Integer
    Dim newRow        As Boolean

    For Each xmlChildNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
        Set xmlAttr = xmlChildNode.Attributes.getNamedItem(attrName)
        If Not xmlAttr Is Nothing Then ' Nodes without name are ignored
            If newRow Then
                ' Repeat values from previous row
                For col = 0 To depth - 1
                    target.Offset(0, col) = target.Offset(-1, col)
                Next
            End If
            target.Offset(0, depth) = xmlAttr.Text
            If Not DisplayXmlTree(xmlChildNode, attrName, target, depth + 1) Then
                Set target = target.Offset(1)
            End If
            newRow = True
        End If
    Next
    DisplayXmlTree = xmlNode.ChildNodes.Length > 0
End Function

Sub LoadXML(filename As String, attrName As String, target As Range)
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    If Dir(filename) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Could not find file " & filename
    ElseIf Not xmlDoc.Load(filename) Then
        MsgBox "Could not parse file " & filename
    Else
        DisplayXmlTree xmlDoc.DocumentElement, attrName, target
        MsgBox "Successfully loaded " & filename
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code uses recursion to go through the XML tree. Here is how you call it, specifying the file to load, the name of the attribute to display, and the target cell where you want the display to start.

```vb
Sub Main()
    LoadXML "C:\Users\myself\Desktop\input.xml", "Name", Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Output will be like this:

[image]

### 2. Display all attribute values in columns, nodes in rows

This was my first answer before you had specified the output format:

```vb
Sub LoadXML(filename As String, target As Range)
    Dim xmlDoc   As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNode  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xmlAttr  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim rows     As Integer
    Dim cols     As Integer

    If Dir(filename) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Could not find file " & filename
    ElseIf Not xmlDoc.Load(filename) Then
        MsgBox "Could not parse file " & filename
    Else
        For Each xmlNode In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
            If InStr(xmlNode.nodeName, "Child") = 1 Then
                cols = 0
                For Each xmlAttr In xmlNode.Attributes
                    target.Offset(rows, cols) = xmlAttr.Text
                    cols = cols + 1
                Next
                rows = rows + 1
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Successfully loaded " & filename
    End If
End Sub
```

When calling this function you pass it the full path of theXML file name, and the cell where the content should start to be output.

So a call could look like this:

```vb
Sub Main()
    LoadXML "C:\Users\myself\Desktop\input.xml", Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Output will be like this:

[image]